# smtplib connect() call always times out

Tags: python-3.x, email-validation, smtplib

I am trying to verify email addresses using this approach (see below) that is cited and recommended in one form or another in countless different places. The problem is that when I get to the "server.connect(mxRecord)" part, **it stalls & times out 100% of the time.**

I have tried:

- at least 30 different domain names to make sure this isn't some networking issue that's specific to a certain domain
- adjusting the timeout limit
- explicitly specifying the port to connect over (465 & 587)
- running "smtplib.SMTP_SSL()" instead of "smtplib.SMTP()"

My setup:

- Home wifi
- No proxies

```
import dns.resolver
import smtplib
import socket

addressToVerify = 'rickymartin@yahoo.com'
domainToVerify = 'yahoo.com'

records = dns.resolver.query(domainToVerify, 'MX')
mxRecord = records[0].exchange
mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
print(mxRecord)

server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=20)
server.set_debuglevel(0)
server.connect(mxRecord)
server.helo(server.local_hostname)
server.mail('me@domain.com')
code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
server.quit()

if code == 250:
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email-validator.py", line 17, in <module>
    server.connect(mxRecord)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

To unblock your execution from timeout, use system timeout exception for this.

```
except TimeoutError as t:
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an SMTP server, to get this working.

From the [SMTP documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html)

> smtplib.SMTP(host='', port=0, local_hostname=None, [timeout,]source_address=None)

> It takes a 2-tuple (host, port), for the socket to bind to as its source address before connecting. If omitted (or if host or port are '' and/or 0 respectively) the OS default behavior will be used.

You get the timeout because the connection can't be establised.
Try to find and use some free SMTP servers or use a docker image and set it up locally.